# How to calculate Flow Rate in Dispensing System?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

This is for a Fluid dispensing system. To be used to dispense a paste-like material.
The issue is that I need a specific amount of material to be within tolerances.
The system dispenses from a Gantry unit which moves in the x-y directions Z is fixed.
The Gantry moves at a speed of 6 in/s (152 mm/s)

The material is in a container 600mm above the table.  90 PSI is constantly supplied to the top of this container.  A 670mm tube extends down to a 90 degree turn with a 45 degree radius.  The tube leads into a electronically actuated valve, which opens 100%.  This valve also acts as another 90 degree turn. At the bottom of the valve is Nozzle which is perpendicular to the table.  The nozzle will be 50 mm above the table. (this height is adjustable)

### Variables

---

Density of the fluid (ρ): 2.329 g/cm^3 
Viscosity of the fluid (μ): 65000 mPa*s 
Inner radius of the tube (r_tube): 0.25 cm 
Length of the tube (l_tube): 67 cm 
Inner radius of Nozzle Tip (r_noz) : 0.03405 cm 
Lenght of the Nozzle (l_noz): 1.8 cm 
Pressure at the beginning of the tube (p1): 90 psi 
Pressure at the nozzle (p2): 14.7 psi 
Height of the fluid container (h1): 60 cm 
Height of the nozzle (h2): 5 cm 
Target Flow Out of Nozzle (Qt): 0.1168 ml/s

Fluid is not compressible.

Calculations:

---

Using Poiseuille's Law:

$
Q = \frac{(p2 - p1) \pi * r^4}{8 * \mu * l}
$

I calculated the Flow Rate at the nozzle to be: 0.002342 ml/s

With this Flow rate the Velocity at the Nozzle was determined: 0.643 cm/s

Problems:

---

My required target Flow Rate is: 0.1168 ml/s 
This was determined by actual measurements of a component within Tolerance.

A secondary issue which will need to be addressed is the spread of the material.
I required a spread of 6mm wide within a area 152 mm long.

Currently I do not know how accurate my calculation is, or if this is proper approach to this application.

Comment: You would probably do better by finding a small positive displacement pump whose flow rate could be adjusted.  For that type of pump, the pump's discharge pressure and the pressure drop in the tube and the nozzle will vary to ensure the constant flow that was selected.

Comment: The first thing to check is the rheology of the paste.  It sounds like the viscosity of the paste is shear rate dependent.  The paste may behave like a Bingham plastic, with a finite deformation stress.  Can you provide a schematic of the geometric arrangement, since describing it in words seems a little complicated.